# Firebase C++ SDK Desktop how to get connection status?

Tags: c++, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase C++ SDK on Windows, is there a way I can get connection status to firebase?
I have checked ".info/connected" and listen to its changed in value, but it does not work correctly, it gives status only when I get connected to Internet again, and only works one time, after that it just does not listen for changes. Here is the code i am using:

```
class ConnectionValueListener : public ValueListener
{
public:
    void OnValueChanged(const firebase::database::DataSnapshot& snapshot) override
    {
        bool status = snapshot.value().AsBool().bool_value();

        if (!status) {
            return;
        }


        auto res = databaseRef.OnDisconnect()->SetValue(isOfflineForDatabase);

        if (res.error() == firebase::database::kErrorNone) {
            res = databaseRef.OnDisconnect()->SetValue(isOnlineForDatabase);
            return;
        }
    }

    void OnCancelled(const firebase::database::Error& error_code, const char* error_message) override
    {
        LogMessage("ValueListener canceled: " + std::to_string(error_code) + error_message);
    }
};
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: i have added the code which is basically from firebase SDK documentation, but the question is really how to get connection status on Desktop.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you modify the code to log the status you get, and then edit your question to contain the updated code and its output?

Comment: Yes, actually the problem is that the future return from OnDisconnect never completes and times out.
But if i have OnDisconnect outside ValueListener it works fine. 
Maybe on Desktop this feature is not available

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen do you any idea why does it fails?

Comment: Nope sorry, I have no experience with that, so hope that somebody else spots the problem.